How to get "changes requested" info on Gitlab MR
I would like to see for which Gitlab MRs changes were requested.
For example, if I approve a MR, I clearly see that in MR list:

But if I request changes, I don't see that info on the list, I need to open the specific MR:

I can't enable this on or at least I didn't find it in any settings, so I want to make a CI/CD script that would be run on each code push which would look into the Gitlab API and add a special label on the MR.
The problem here is that I cannot find this info on any of the following endpoints.
I tried:

/api/v4/projects/{:id}/merge_requests/{:iid} has detailed_merge_status which should by definition could have a status requested_changes state according to docs, but the only statuses that I get are discussions_not_resolved, draft and mergeable. The last one is especially misleading, because the MR that I'm teseting on has changes requested by one reviewer, but still the status is mergable
/api/v4/projects/{:id}/merge_requests/{:iid}/notes - couldn't find any usefull info here
/api/v4/projects/{:id}/merge_requests/{:iid}/disscusions - couldn't find any usefull info here

Is there any other endpoint that I am missing?
The next thing I tried was a /request_changes quick action , but it seems that it gets stripped away. I also couldn't find any information about it in docs, even tho I get it as a suggestion in the Gitlabu UI.

